# how to invoke vscode in ssh mode from the command line

Tags: visual-studio-code

With the ssh extension of vscode I can open `remotedir` in `remotehost` via the UI. Similarly to how you can invoke `code localdir` in the command line, is it possible to do something like `code remotedir --host remotehost`? If not, would there be a way to write a script to achieve something like that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use:

```
code --folder-uri "vscode-remote://ssh-remote+remote_server/folder/on/remote/host/here
```

To also specify the user:

```
code --folder-uri "vscode-remote://ssh-remote+remote_user@remote_server/folder/on/remote/host/here
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I _am_ one of those readers in the future, and this is exactly the answer I need. Further explanation would be clutter.

Comment: Thanks. Works for me. But first, it was not obvious to me what should I replace. My example:
`code --folder-uri "vscode-remote://ssh-remote+john_doe@my.server.com/home/john_doe/workdir/myproject`

Answer (score 0):

One way has been described in the link below:
[Remote Development using SSH](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh).

As you can see in the middle of the page, "*Opening a terminal on a remote host*", it points out you have to establish an ssh connection first then when you write `code .` will automatically run on the remote host rather than locally.

Hope it works.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question of how to open vscode in remote mode from the command line in the first place. The link you shared assumes that you are already inside vscode's terminal with the ssh connection established.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure if this is what you are looking for, but can you check [Code Server](https://github.com/cdr/code-server).

It runs VS Code remotely and you can access its UI using a Browser.

Comment: No, I'm aware of code server, but I want to use regular vscode, I just need to open it in ssh mode from the command line.

Comment: https://codeyarns.com/2018/05/03/how-to-edit-remote-files-using-remote-vscode/ Check this then

Answer (score 0):

You can start a GUI on your remote pc from your local display [here check this out](https://ahelpme.com/linux/commandline/start-gui-program-on-the-remote-machine-using-your-local-display-through-ssh/) or you can configure a VNC server [tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/installation-of-vnc-server-on-ubuntu-1cf035370bd3) and connect to your remote machine via a VNC client [real vnc](https://www.realvnc.com/en/)
after all of this, you can either view the remote screen from SSH or from VNC. I recommend using VNC. so you can have full control of your remote host.

after the screen share is done you can either use terminal `code .` to open the vs code inside your project folder or use application to open the folder directly.

Comment: vscode already has ssh functionality, I just want to be able to open it from the command line. VNC is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're actually wanting to do is automatically connect to a Remote Explorer ssh target directory from the command line, a way to do this would be to connect normally in vscode, save the workspace, then open the workspace from the command line, it should autoconnect back to the same ssh host and directory.